# Google Cloud Storage Folder Structure

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

Does Google Cloud Storage support any functionality that will allow me to nest referenced files contained in a microsite as is described here by rackspace cloud.

http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Pseudo-Hierarchical_Folders_Directories-d1e1580.html

As in, if I upload an html page that references css and script files that I also want to store in google cloud storage...is there a way to accomplish this sort of dynamic file nesting on Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, certainly. Google Cloud Storage similarly does not have true "folders", but you can certainly use delimiter characters like "/", which will behave appropriately if you are hosting a static website. You can similarly list objects using prefixes and delimiters. The "prefix" could represent a "current directory", and the "delimiter" could be a "/", representing a subdirectory. See https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list for more precise descriptions on object listing parameters.